# Nested JSON to Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

There are already posts talking about this, but I am still not able to figure out my problem.

I am accessing my database and am converting the response into a JSON object - that part is working fine. Here is the code for that. `joArray` now has the data I need.

```
//Convert data to json object
let joArray : NSArray
do {
    joArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSArray
}
catch  {
    print(responseString)
    print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
    return
 }
```

If I print out joArray . . .

```
print(joArray)
```

. . . this is what I get.

```
(
        {
        FirstName = Bob;
    },
        {
        FirstName = Bill;
    }
)
```

How can I put this data into a swift array so that it looks like this?

```
let FirstNameArray = ["Bob", "Bill"]
```

FirstName will always be in the same position, but there will be varying numbers of users (Bob, Bill, Mary, etc.).

Comment: Hard to jugde without knowing the exact JSON. Your print-out is most like only a small part of it. You get an array of dictionaries. You have to `(flat)map` the array to your desired format. Side-note: **Do not** use `NSArray` in Swift. You defeat the strong type system by throwing away the crucial type information. Use native `Array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will make life easier for yourself if you use a native Swift array instead. So, start by changing your array definition:

```
let joArray: [[String: Any]]
do {
  joArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [[String: Any]]
} catch {
  // etc...
}
```

Now, it's straightforward to construct the required array:

```
let FirstNameArray = swiftArray.flatMap { $0["FirstName"] }
```

You should use `flatMap`, rather than `map`, because the given array item might not have a property called `"FirstName"`.